# Балансировка между процессами на разных серверах

Tags: php, процесс

Имеется 4 сервера, на каждом из серверов запущено по 4 `php` процесса (демона), которые рассылают смс нотификации. На данном этапе проблема заключается в том что скрипты работают только на том сервере которому на данный момент присвоен VIP. То есть вся нагрузка от процессов падает на 1 сервер. Как реализовать балансировщик так чтобы рассылка распределялась между всеми процессами на разных серверах, и в случае падения сервера,распределялась между оставшимися.

Привожу ниже кусок кода из скрипта демона

```
while (true)
{
    $params = array('limit' => $limitRecords);
    
    $requests = $request->getRequests($params);
    
    if (!$requests)
    {
        sleep(3);
    }
    else
    {
        $requestsTotal = count($requests);
        
        foreach ($requests as $req)
        {
            $cmdNewProcess = "/usr/bin/php " . __DIR__  . "/request_sender.php " . $req['phone_number'] . " " . $req['notification_text'];
            exec($cmdNewProcess . " > /dev/null &");
        }
        
        sleep($sleepInterval);
    }
}
```

Comment: Я не спец, но я бы сделал случайное распределение между серверами которые онлайн. Вот есть какая-то очередь, и сервера по очереди берут из нее задачу и выполняют. Кто первый ухватил - тот и выполняет

Comment: А откуда демоны черпают информацию что посылать и куда посылать ?

Comment: Есть таблица с подготовленными смс, текста отправитель и так далее, демон мониторит ее, если данных нет слипается на пару сек чтобы базу не мучать, если есть начинается рассылка и так по кругу

Comment: А что за база ? Она где расположена, прямо на сервере ? А если он упадет, то что произойдет с базой, у нее есть какое то отражение на других серверах ?

Comment: 2 отдельных сервера, Oracle СУБД с настроенной отказоустойчивостью

Comment: И не жалко вам ресурсов на постоянное порождение новых процессов ... Ладно, ваше дело конечно. Но я бы все переделал. Сразу бы один раз стартовал нужное количество процессов и что бы каждый вычитывал записи и блочил их, пока не отработает. Общий подход: начинаем транзакцию. `SELECT ... FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED`. обрабатываем, когда точно знаем что обработали, возможно апдейтим (в той же транзакции !) завершаем транзакцию. ...

Comment: На этом все, можно запускать любое количество обработчиков на любом количестве серверов. Потому как обработчик берет запись и блочит ее (т.е. никто другой ее уже for update не возьмет). Другой обработчик прочитает другую запись, так как пропустит заблокированные другими процессами

Comment: P.S. А учитывая, что отправка СМС наверняка сетевая операция (и подозреваю, что http) по идее можно реализовать все вообще в одном процессе, используя асинхронную работу с сетью, но это уже совсем другая история ...

Comment: P.P.S А еще подозреваю что от постоянного опроса таблицы в современном Oracle то же можно избавиться. Средства ожидания событий должны уже существовать, но об этом лучше отдельно спросить, думаю 0xdb ответит

Comment: Спасибо, идея с локом записей мне понравилась. Проанализирую глубже данный момент. Единственный момент как понять каждому ворерку по сколько записей брать, если один упадет остальные должны между собой разделить

Comment: Т.е. вы хотите сохранять примерно одинаковый темп отправки, при том, что входящая очередь может расти ? Не надо отправлять с максимально возможной скоростью, что бы очередь по возможности не наполнялась ?

Comment: Для решения в лоб можно в рассыльщике установить на сессию к ораклу какие нибудь имя модуля (см. `DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_MODULE`), дать права на чтение `v$session` и периодически получать количество подключенных в данный момент к ораклу обработчиков чем то вроде `select count(1) from v$session where module='X'`. Но надо понимать, что при падении какого либо сервера соединение с БД может не сразу порваться. И большой вопрос что происходит с v$session если у вас два сервера БД, возможно придется подключаться к какому то конкретному

Comment: ну либо городить огород что бы рассыльщики друг с другом общались постоянно что бы знать свой статус, через сокеты. но что то мне подсказывает что задача не стоит того что бы так заморачиваться

Comment: Ранее решали подобный вопрос остатком от деления, то есть каждый воркер брал записи каждый с разным остатком от деления, но если один из них падал, записи которуе предназначались ему висели в простое. Поэтому хочется сделать гибкое решение, при падении любого, распределение между оставшимися

Comment: по блокированию простоя не будет. он же будет хватать первую же свободную запись

Answer (score 1):

Можете использовать любую библиотеку или систему распределённой очереди, например [beanstalkD](https://beanstalkd.github.io/). Запускаете сервер, затем рабочих, и назначаете задачи, которые будут отданы рабочим. Аналогично можно использовать [GearmanServer с GearmanWorker](http://gearman.org/manual/)

Comment: Сразу напрашивается вопрос, если система распределения очереди будет на каждом сервере, тогда понадобится и репликация между ними я правильно понимаю?

Comment: Это рабочие будут на разных серверах; сервер задач будет один, и с него будут распределяться задачи на сервера рабочих.